# How to create a vector and increment it based on another vector?

Tags: r, increment

Let's say I have the following vector of repeating letters:

```
a = rep(LETTERS, 5)[3:130]
```

which looks like:

> "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "A" "B" ...

I would like to create a second numerical vector of the same length that starts at variable "n" and increases by 1 when a contains "A" (ie the next alphabet).

```
n = 45
```

Which should look something like this:

> 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 47 47 ...

I know that I can find the indices at which these changes will occur with the following:

```
which(a == "A")

25 51 77 103
```

But I'm not sure of an efficient way to make this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = rep(LETTERS, 5)[3:130]
n = 45
n + cumsum(a == "A")
# [1] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46
# [33] 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47
# [65] 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
# [97] 48 48 48 48 48 48 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `which`:

```
a = rep(LETTERS, 5)[3:130]
n = 45

indices <- which(a == "A")
result <- rep(n, length(a))

for (idx in indices) {
  result[idx:length(a)] <- result[idx:length(a)] + 1
}

result
```

```
[1] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
 [19] 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46
 [37] 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 47 47 47 47
 [55] 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47
 [73] 47 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
 [91] 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 49 49 49 49 49 49
[109] 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49
[127] 49 49
```